# jQuery ajax call to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

For my Phonegap/Cordova project I'm trying to handle all ajax calls with the following functions:

```
function requestData(action, id ) {
    var data = {
        user_id: localStorage.getItem('user_id')
    };
    if( action == 'feed_load_feedings' || action == 'feed_add_load_menu_weight' || action == 'feed_add_load_menu_supps' ) {
        data.id = id;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://_______.com/file.php?'+action,
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: showLoader,
        error: handleError,
        success: handleSuccess
    });
}
function showLoader() {
    console.log('showLoader fired')
    $('body').prepend('<p id="loading">De gegevens worden geladen...</p>');
}
function handleError(data) {
    console.log('handleError fired')
    $('#loading').remove();
    $('body').prepend('<p id="error">Fout tijdens het laden van de gegevens...</p>');
    return false;
}
function handleSuccess(data) {
    console.log('handleSuccess fired')
    $('#loading').remove();
    if( typeof data !== 'object' ) {
        $('body').prepend('<p id="error">Fout in gegevens object...</p>');
        return false;
    }
    else if(data.length == 0 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return data;
    }
}
```

This handles the request, but also the error handling.

If everything is alright, it should return the data. However using this:

```
$(function() {
    var herd = requestData('herd_load_herds');
    console.log(herd):
});
```

Gives this in the console:

```
showLoader fired
POST http://_______.com/file.php?feed_load_feedings
handleSuccess fired
undefined
```

In the POST request I can see that the data is called and okay. However it isn't put into the variable. I thought that adding `async: false` to my ajax call would prevent that. What am I overseeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The reason behind returning undefined is pretty obvious since `requestData` function doesn't return anything which means it indirectly returns `undefined`

The flow of the ajax is asynchronous, so returning anything in the function `requestData` won't work. You need to pass callback function in function calling and execute it in the success/ error handlers.

```
$(function() {
    requestData('herd_load_herds', 'someid', function(err, data){
      if(err){
        console.log("error");
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        console.log("success");
        console.log(data):
      }
    });    
});
```

in AJAX:

```
function requestData(action, id, callback) {
    var data = {
        user_id: localStorage.getItem('user_id')
    };
    if( action == 'feed_load_feedings' || action == 'feed_add_load_menu_weight' || action == 'feed_add_load_menu_supps' ) {
        data.id = id;
    } 
    $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://_______.com/file.php?'+action,
            async: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            data: data,
            beforeSend: showLoader,
            error: function(error){
              handleError(error, callback);
            },
            success: function(data){
              handleSuccess(data, callback);
            }
        });
}
```

In handler:

```
function handleSuccess(data, next) {
    console.log('handleSuccess fired')
    $('#loading').remove();
    if( typeof data !== 'object' ) {
        $('body').prepend('<p id="error">Fout in gegevens object...</p>');
        next(undefined, false);
    }else{       
      next(undefined, data);
    }
}

function handleError(err, next) {
    console.log('handleError fired')
    $('#loading').remove();
    $('body').prepend('<p id="error">Fout tijdens het laden van de gegevens...</p>');
    next(err);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried your code but it gives me an error: `TypeError: next is not a function`... how come?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working perfectly fine. JavaScript functions without a return value return `undefined` by default. Your function `requestData` has no `return <someValue>` statement and so returns the default `undefined`.

If you want to save the data, you need to save it in the `success` callback.

My advise is to not try and hack around with `async: false`. Just do everything async and respond to callbacks appropriately.

Comment: That does make sence. But how can I get the data from the `success` callback into the `herd` variable?

Comment: "My advise is to not try and hack around with `async: false`". I've read about it and am with you. But I would like to handle all my ajax request from these scripts. So I've something changes, I only need to change it once. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Make `herd` global and then save to it (`herd = data`) in your `success` callback